# What sidequests can be done before getting Excalibur II?

Tags: final-fantasy-9

In order to obtain Excalibur II in Final Fantasy IX, the player has to reach *Gate to Space*, a room in *Memoria* in under 12 hours of playtime.

That obviously means that several sidequests will have to be ignored, and some areas left unexplored, especially because some areas are inacessible after Disc 3.

However (excluding sidequests that can be done after getting the sword) what quests can actually be done, without compromising the ultimate goal (Excalibur II). Or in other words, what sidequests could be done during a Final Fantasy IX **12-hour speedrun** playthrough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything in the game can be achieved, even with a 12-hour speedrun. Take a look at this [Excalibur II perfect guide by Atomos199](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps/197338-final-fantasy-ix/faqs/41181).

Hope you got some time, there is really much to read. Hope you are crazy too... But once more (because I know you cannot believe it at first) : you CAN (does not mean you should) do a perfect game with Excalibur II.